# How do I transfer material from high poly mesh to low poly?

Tags: texture-baking, baking

I have created a monster in Blender's geometry nodes, and now am in the process of baking everything onto a low poly model.

I have now run into some trouble as I am trying to transfer the materials through texture baking, and was wondering if anyone could give any suggestions on how I can proceed.

Below is a picture of the original monster: I extruded the mesh using a wave texture, and then applied a different material to the extruded mesh using a set material node. After that is a picture of my low poly model.

I have figure out how to bake the normals so that my low poly mesh has the wave patterns, but how do I bake the material (pink and purple colors) onto the low mesh model as well?

Thanks so much!!
[image]

[image]

Comment: to bake the Diffuse you need to create an Image Texture with a new image, keep this node selected, choose Bake Type > Diffuse, disable Contributions > Direct and Indirect, activate Selected to Active, and bake, if it doesn't work please share your file

Comment: thank you! I will give it a go